# Update Tkinter progressbar from function called (by button click), function is in separate document

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar

I am trying to update progressbar in tkinter.
First of i have two documents.
document 1: conatins GUI
document 2: Contains functions, that are called when pressing the button widgets attached to the GUI.

When i perform a calculation within document 2 i want to update the progress bar which is in document 1.
An exaple of the code is as follows. (just to mention, this is my first script in python, so please correct me if im wrong in any of the coding)

```
#Document 1 
from Document2 import *

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import font as tkfont # python 3
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar




class TEST(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.resizable(self, width=False, height=False)
        tk.Tk.title(self, "APP NAME")
        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, filepath_NAME_icon)
        tk.Tk.geometry(self, "465x262")

        #self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (ProjectingPage):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("ProjectingPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()




class ProjectingPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg=bg_color)
        self.controller = controller


        Button_get_TK = Button(self, text="Indsæt terrænkote",
                               font=("Calibri", btn_font_size, "normal"),
                               width=std_button_width,
                               bg=bg_color_button,
                               fg=fg_color_button,
                               borderwidth=size_border_width,
                               activebackground=act_bg,
                               command=Get_TK)
        Button_get_TK.place(x=12, y=166)
        Button_get_TK.update()

        self.progress = Progressbar(self, orient = HORIZONTAL,
              length = 100, mode = 'determinate')
        self.progress.pack()

    def UpdateProgressBar(self, data):
        self.progress.start()
        self.progress.update_idletasks()
```

and

```
#Document 2
import Document1 as KTP
from Document1 import *

def Get_TK():
    for i in range(0,100):
        test_progressbar = KTP.ProjectingPage
        test_progressbar.UpdateProgressBar(i)
```

I have trimmed down my code to just the relevant part. I need to know the principals of getting my progressbar to update by calling a function from a separate document.

I really hope someone can help me. thanks in advance :-)

Comment: "_I have trimmed down my code to just the relevant part._" ~ Does not look like that to me

Comment: This example does not function. For us to help you, you must create a minimal example that shows your problems and can be easily run for testing.

Comment: maybe first create minimal working code with `test_progressbar` because updateing it inside `for` loop may block `mainloop`

Comment: don't import `Document1` into `Document2` because it create `circular import` and it can makes problem. Simply you should't hardcoded value from other file but you send it as argument - `def Get_TK(KTP):` - and then you may run it in `Document1` as `command=lambda:Get_TK(KTP)` - like so you don't need to import `KTP` into `Document2`.

Comment: as for me `Get_TK` should be in separated file but rather it should be part of class `ProjectingPage`

Comment: it is only suggestion but many people respect it: `CamelCaseNames` for classes but for functions/methods/variable `lower_case_namese` - ie. `def update_progressbar` instead of `def UpdateProgressBar`. It helps to recognize classes in code. More: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peppep-0008/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't uses elements from `Document1` as hardcoded in `Document2` but as argument in function.

```
#Document 2
# without imports from Document1

def Get_TK(item):
    test_progressbar = item.ProjectingPage
    for i in range(100):
        test_progressbar.UpdateProgressBar(i)
```

And then I would use lambda to assing function with values

```
command=lambda:Get_TK(self.UpdateProgressBar):
```

I would said that sending as argument is consistent with the principle of [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

```
Explicit is better than implicit.
```

---

But if I would have to use `Get_TK` in `ProjectingPage` to access element in the same class `ProjectingPage` then I wouldn't put it in separated file but directly in `ProjectingPage`

```
class ProjectingPage(tk.Frame):

    def Get_TK(self):
        for i in range(100):
            self.UpdateProgressBar(i)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was really helpful and solved my problem!! The reason i want to keep it in separate documents is because i have a ton of functions i need to call from document 2. So to make it more managable when im writing/editing code for the gui i chose to keep it in totally separate documents :-) YOU SAVED MY DAY furas!!

Comment: I would said that sending as argument is consistent with the principle of [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) - 
`Explicit is better than implicit.`